# Where should the System.Collections.Concurrent collections be used?

Tags: c#, collections, thread-safety

and how do they differ from the non-thread safe collections? A small code example comparing the two approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: When you need to access them concurrently?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN: [When to Use a Thread-Safe Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373.aspx)